# Different behavior between running command with prefix sudo and as root user, seemingly sudo is less authorized

Tags: linux, shell, root, sudo

I want to disable Address Space Layout Randomization(ASLR) by echoing 0 into `/proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space`. But I failed to do so in normal user mode even with prefix `sudo`:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
2
$ sudo echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
zsh: permission denied: /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
```

When I tried the same process after login as root user, I succeed.

```
$ su 
# cat /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
2
# echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
# cat /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
0
```

I wonder why commands running with prefix sudo failed but as root user succeed. What is the difference between sudo and root? I tried this experiment on a Linux system and a WSL and they all exhibit the same phenomenon. The two profiles of my experimented environments are

```
5.10.0-kali3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.13-1kali1 (2021-02-08)
4.4.0-19041-Microsoft #488-Microsoft Mon Sep 01 13:43:00 PST 2020
```

Comment: Redirection happens before `sudo` is run. This is a feature.

Comment: @Gereon Thank you. I succeed in executing with `sudo sh -c 'echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space'`